# MySQL query for distinct rows on count

Tags: mysql, select

I have such query that gives me results about bestseller items from shops, at the moment it works fine, but now I want to get only one product from each shop so to have a distinct `si`.`shop_id` only one bestseller product from a shop

```
SELECT  `si`.`id`, si.shop_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `transaction_item` AS `tis` 
JOIN `transaction` as `t` 
ON `t`.`id` = `tis`.`transaction_id` 
WHERE `tis`.`shop_item_id` = `si`.`id` 
AND `t`.`added_date` >= '2014-02-26 00:00:00')
AS `count`
FROM `shop_item` AS `si` 
INNER JOIN `transaction_item` AS `ti` 
ON ti.shop_item_id = si.id 
GROUP BY `si`.`id` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 7
```

and that gives mu a result like:

```
+--------+---------+-------+
|   id   | shop_id | count |
+--------+---------+-------+
| 425030 |   38027 |   111 |
| 291974 |    5368 |    20 |
| 425033 |   38027 |    18 |
| 291975 |    5368 |    12 |
| 142776 |    5368 |    10 |
| 397016 |   38027 |     9 |
| 291881 |    5368 |     8 |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

any ideas?

EDIT
so I created a fiddle for it
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc4c/1

Now the query returns best selling products I want it to return only one product from shopso the result of fiddle should be

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | SHOP_ID | COUNT |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |     222 |     3 |
|  4 |     333 |     2 |
|  8 |     555 |     1 |
|  9 |     777 |     1 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.  How do you know what items are in a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this:-

```
SELECT  si.shop_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', si.id, sub1.item_count) ORDER BY sub1.item_count DESC), ',', 1) AS `count`
FROM shop_item AS si 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT tis.shop_item_id, COUNT(*) AS item_count
    FROM transaction_item AS tis 
    JOIN `transaction` as t 
    ON t.id = tis.transaction_id 
    AND t.added_date >= '2014-02-26 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY tis.shop_item_id
) sub1
ON sub1.shop_item_id = si.id 
GROUP BY si.shop_id 
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 7
```

The sub query gets the count of items for each shop. Then the main query concatenates the item id and the item count together, group concatenates all those for a single shop together (ordered by the count descending) and then uses SUBSTRING_INDEX to grab the first one (ie, everything before the first comma).

You will have to split up the count field to get the item id and count separately (the separator is a : ).

This is taking a few guesses about what you really want, and with no table declares or data it isn't tested.

EDIT - now tested with the SQL fiddle example:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`count`, ':', 1) AS ID,
    shop_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`count`, ':', -1) AS `count`
FROM
(
    SELECT  si.shop_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', si.id, sub1.item_count) ORDER BY sub1.item_count DESC), ',', 1) AS `count`
    FROM shop_item AS si 
    INNER JOIN transaction_item AS ti 
    ON ti.shop_item_id = si.id 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT tis.shop_item_id, COUNT(*) AS item_count
        FROM transaction_item AS tis 
        JOIN `transaction` as t 
        ON t.id = tis.transaction_id 
        AND t.added_date >= '2014-02-26 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY tis.shop_item_id
    ) sub1
    ON sub1.shop_item_id = si.id 
    GROUP BY si.shop_id 

) sub2
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: Ok mayby this will help, I created a Fiddle uder http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc4c/1 check update

Comment: Tested and amended to give you the data in the format you want.

Comment: Can you update the SQL fiddle to demonstrate the issue please.

Comment: this will be hard to find cause I simplified the data structures in those tables just to have necessary fields... does it change anything if there can be many products in one transaction?

Comment: Don't think so, although looking at the SQL I think I can remove one of the joins to transaction_item (modded my code now)

Comment: not even close... I must find what makes the difference between the fiddle base and the real one that it gives diferent results